# Mongo finone where condition and cond1 or cond2

Tags: mongodb

How do you do this simple select in mongodb?

```
Select  * 
From    messages 
Where   id = $id 
        And 
        (
            user_id = $user->_id 
            Or 
            from_user_id = $user->_id
        )
```

This is what I have so far...

```
$msg = Message::model()->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id), 'user_id' => $user->_id));
```

Comment: Since `_id` is a unique primary key the other conditions do not make any sense since only the first condition will match.

Comment: it's a validation. I want to be sure that this message belongs to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your point is clear, all query conditions in MongoDB are implicitly an "AND" condition unless specified otherwise. So here you combine this with an explicit [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

```js
db.collection.findOne({
    "_id": id,
    "$or": [
        "user_id": userId,
        "from_user_id": userId
    ]
})
```

Which either returns the message or nothing

Answer (score 1):

The mongo query you need looks like this:

```
findOne({
  _id: id,
  $or: [
    { user_id: userId },
    { from_user_id: userId }
  ]
})
```

You seem to be using PHP, in which case it'll look something like:

```
Message::model()->findOne(array(
  '_id' => new MongoId($id),
  '$or' => [
    array('user_id' => $user->_id), 
    array('from_user_id' => $user->_id)
  ]));
```

I'm not familiar with PHP's array syntax, but I assume it's `[...]`. If not, change the `$or` value appropriately -- it needs to be an array containing two associative arrays, just like in the raw Mongo query above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to you [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) statement (everything else is by default `and`)

```
db.messages.findOne({
  '_id': id,
  '$or': [{
     'user_id': userId
  }, { 
     'from_user_id': userId
  }]
})
```